# Excel Online | Return Cell Formula - Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

For Excel Online, I want to get the formula contained inside a cell.

Currently, I'm using getDataAsync() but it only returns the final result but not the formula:

```
Office.select('bindings#ObjSelect').getDataAsync({ coercionType: 'matrix', startRow: 0, startCol: 0, rowCount: 1, colCount: 1 }, 
    function (result) {
        console.log(result.value);
});
```

Is there a way to return the formula?

Comment: Excel 2013 has the native [ISFORMULA function](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/ISFORMULA-function-e4d1355f-7121-4ef2-801e-3839bfd6b1e5?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) and [FORMULATEXT function](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/FORMULATEXT-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) but I'm not sufficiently conversant in mashing Excel and Javascript together to suggest any syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jeeped mentioned, Excel has native ISFORMULA and FORMULATEXT functions. You can create worker cells that will display the formula and simply return the data.

```
//Bind Cells
Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync("A1:XFD1048576", "matrix", { id: 'objSelect'},function(e){

});

//Set Worker Cell
Office.select('bindings#workerCell').setDataAsync([['=FORMULATEXT('+Cell+')']],
    {startRow: 0, startColumn:99},function (asyncResult){

});

//Get Function
Office.select('bindings#objCell').getDataAsync({ coercionType: 'matrix', startRow: 0, startCol: 99, rowCount: 1, colCount: 1 }, 
        function (result) {
            console.log(result.value[0]);
    });
```

And that will sort it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use range's **formulas** property, reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt598656.aspx)

```
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var selectedRange = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();
        selectedRange.load('formulas'); // IMPORTANT, it tells Excel to load formulas

        return ctx.sync().then(function () {
            var formula = '';
            if (selectedRange.formulas !== undefined)) {
                formula = selectedRange.formulas[0][0];
            }

            if (formula.length > 0) {
                // do something here with the 'formula'
            }
        });
    });
```